# How to configure Auto-Value with Eclipse and Gradle?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, auto-value

I want to use Google’s Auto-Value in a Gradle java-library project in Eclipse.

My class:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Pairing implements Comparable<Pairing> {

    static Pairing create(final Participant white, final Participant black) {
    return new AutoValue_Participant(white, black);
    }

    private final transient Participant white;
    private final transient Participant black;

}
```

https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md says: To use Auto-Value in Gradle, simply use:

```
dependencies {
  // Use 'api' rather than 'compile' for Android or java-library projects.
  compile             "com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2"
  annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.6.2"
}
```

I did this, and it didn’t work:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
D:\QNo_Dokumente\Java\workspace\SwissCoffee\src\main\java\de\qno\swisscoffee\Pairing.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    return new AutoValue_Participant(white, black);
               ^
  symbol:   class AutoValue_Participant
  location: class Pairing
D:\QNo_Dokumente\Java\workspace\SwissCoffee\build\classes\java\main\de\qno\swisscoffee\AutoValue_Pairing.java:11: error: constructor Pairing in class Pairing cannot be applied to given types;
```

Then i googled and found a Gradle APT plugin that should solve all problems. But the documentation of the plugin says: it is unnecessary for Gradle >= 4.6, and since i’m using gradle 5.4, i should be fine without that plugin.

How get i Auto-Value integrated?

Comment: Are you sure about the Gradle version? Do you use the Gradle wrapper? Sometimes an old installation might be used, because `gradle` is called instead of `gradlew`.

Comment: A valid question. But i just did a clean-up. Fresh installations of Java, Eclipse, Gradle, no older versions on disk. It might have been otherwise: Fresh gradle, but stale gradlew. I removed gradlew and gradlew.bat and called gradle wrapper. No changes with gradlew build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you should never code after midnight. And you should solve problems by discarding any code written after midnight.

The source code simply was wrong. Private fields instead of abstract methods, false name of the autoValue autogenerated class.

Sorry for inconvenience. No further reply necessary. All docs found with google are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, unfortunately it did not resolve automatically (using Gradle 8.7, Eclipse 2023-12 and autovalue 1.10.4).

I resolved it by first following the directions in the autovalue documentation for the gradle build dependencies, then adding the generated sources to the build path:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compileOnlyApi      "com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.10.4"
  annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.10.4"
}
sourceSets {
  main {
    java.srcDirs += "build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main"
  }
}
```

After that, Eclipse also found the AutoValue_MyClass generated class. You might need to run "Refresh Gradle Project" (or set Preferences > Gradle > Automatic Project Synchronisation) to apply these changes.